# Pycharm venv with the latest pip version

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, virtualenv, python-venv

I am trying to figure out how to create new PyCharm projects with the latest pip version.

I am setting my Python Interpreter to venv python3.9 and when I install a package with pip I always get a warning that new pip version is availible

Is there a way to upgrade pip version for all new PyCharm projects?

I have tried looking at which python I am using as a base interpreter and updating pip there

`/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`
and
`/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip`

but when i create a new PyCharm project I still get a warning to update pip